# React - convert date with date-fns

Tags: reactjs, date-fns

I have a date in this format: `12-21-2021`
This date comes from a Redux selector.

So `console.log('ccc', lastUpdateDate);` at the beginning shows only:

```
ccc
```

and after few times shows

```
ccc 12-21-202
```

If I use `new Date(lastUpdateDate).toDateString()` it turns out it works only in Chrome, whereas FireFox and Safari say this is an invalid date.

So I want to convert it in the right way using a function.

So I created this function:

```
const parseDateWithDashes = (dateToParse) => {
    console.log('dateToParse', dateToParse);

    useEffect((): any => { 
    let finalDate;
    dateToParse instanceof Date && dateToParse.getTime()
        ? (finalDate = format(dateToParse, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx"))
        : null;

    console.log('finalDate', finalDate);

    return finalDate;
    }, [dateToParse]); //since at the beginning it is empty, it should re-run as a date is available
};

parseDateWithDashes(lastUpdateDate)
```

However doing this it logs out:

```
dateToParse (several time empty)
dateToParse 12-21-2021
finalDate undefined (several times)
```

I've also tried to run the function in a useEffect...

```
useEffect(() => {
    parseDateWithDashes(lastUpdateDate);
});
```

But that's an invalid hook call.

What am I doing wrong? How to fix that?

Comment: Would be acceptable for you an answer that uses a library to manage datetime? Or you prefer to solve your problem in your `parseDateWithDashes` function?

Comment: It can be a library. I am already using in the project `date-fns` - so that library would be the best accepted solution to manage date/tiem

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it this way.

I added the parsing to the thunk. And stringified in order to avoid non-serialized errors:

```
    const parsedDate = parse(lastUpdateDate, 'MM-dd-yyyy', new Date());
    dispatch(setLastUpdateDate(JSON.stringify(parsedDate)));
```

Then I just formatted it in the component:

```
export const convertStringDateToDate = (date: string) => {
    let finalDate;
    try {
        finalDate = JSON.parse(date);
        finalDate = format(parseISO(finalDate), 'E LLL d yyyy');
    } catch (e) {
        finalDate = 'loading date';
    }

    return finalDate;
};
```

That works